# How do I create a conditional form field?

Tags: 8

I have this dropdown menu of options in the user registration page of my site (image shown below), and i want when the user selects the employer, some text fields appear, like name of company, and when they select job seeker, the text field that appears asks for things like uploading CV.

[image: conditional dropdown]

I have conditional fields module installed but it does not cater for user registration form (image shown below) .

Is there a way to add the user registration form to be one of the options that conditional fields module offers? I have followed each of those links and none of them is helpful.:(

[image: conditional fields]

Lastly, in the account type drop down image shown above, I want to filter out the administrator, anonymous user and authenticated user options such that the user only creates either an employer account or job seeker account. Any ideas how i can do that?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please don't use [tag:community-drupal-org] to mean _this is a question about Drupal_. On this site, every question is about Drupal, or it is off-topic. If you want to tag the question with the Drupal version, there are [tag:8], [tag:7], and [tag:6].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using taxonomy terms.  A warning though ... taxonomy worked terribly due to the amount of conditional items.  For my situation, user selected a state, then the town it took about a minute for each selection.

Does this help?  http://www.webbykat.com/2013/04/conditional-fields-and-term-reference-tree-two-small-bugs-their-resolution

I'm assuming you have this Drupal 7 module?  https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Comment: Sorry, I was just commenting that people don't read... I obviously missed the drupal 8.....!  The conditional fields module says they have a pre-release for 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you happy doing some custom coding then you can use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) to alter the form and then use [states](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states) to conditionally hide and show fields. You can also remove the other options from the account type select whilst your there.

For example your code may look something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for user_register_form.
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  // Install devel and uncomment this line to understand the struture of the $form array
  //dpm($form);

  $form['your_field']['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="somefield[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ]
  ];

  unset($form['account_type']['#options']['administrator']);
  unset($form['account_type']['#options']['anonymous user']);

}
```

This code just gives you an idea of the kind of thing required - you will need to modify what is above to fit your exact use case.

This is certainly more complex than using the conditional fields module but is also far more flexible.